# error Public member 'Value' on type 'Integer' not found. exporting data to excel from datagridview including images

Tags: vb.net, excel, datagrid

I have a datagrid which has two image column. I want to export the data to excel. And using this code

```
 SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel Files (*.xlsx*)|*.xlsx"
            SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
            Dim filename As String = SaveFileDialog1.FileName
            'verfying the datagridview having data or not
            If ((DataGridView1.Columns.Count = 0) Or (DataGridView1.Rows.Count = 0)) Then
                Exit Sub
            End If

            'Creating dataset to export
            Dim dset As New DataSet
            'add table to dataset
            dset.Tables.Add()
            'add column to that table
            For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1
                dset.Tables(0).Columns.Add(DataGridView1.Columns(i).HeaderText)
            Next
            'add rows to the table
            Dim dr1 As DataRow
            For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
                dr1 = dset.Tables(0).NewRow
                For j As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
                    Dim cj = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value
                    If (cj.GetType = GetType(Byte())) Then                


     'Error = Publicmember 'Value' on type 'Integer' not found.
                        Dim data As Byte() = DirectCast(cj.Value, Byte())
                        Dim ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream(data)
                        Dim k As System.Drawing.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms)
                        dr1(j) = k
                    Else
                        dr1(j) = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value
                    End If

                Next
                dset.Tables(0).Rows.Add(dr1)
            Next


            Dim excel As New Excel.Application()
            Dim wBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
            Dim wSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet

            wBook = excel.Workbooks.Add()
            wSheet = wBook.ActiveSheet()

            Dim dt As System.Data.DataTable = dset.Tables(0)
            Dim dc As System.Data.DataColumn
            Dim dr As System.Data.DataRow
            Dim colIndex As Integer = 0
            Dim rowIndex As Integer = 0

            For Each dc In dt.Columns
                colIndex = colIndex + 1
                excel.Cells(1, colIndex) = dc.ColumnName
            Next

            For Each dr In dt.Rows
                rowIndex = rowIndex + 1
                colIndex = 0
                For Each dc In dt.Columns
                    colIndex = colIndex + 1
                    excel.Cells(rowIndex + 1, colIndex) = dr(dc.ColumnName)

                Next
            Next

            wSheet.Columns.AutoFit()
            Dim strFileName As String = filename
            Dim blnFileOpen As Boolean = False
            Try
                Dim fileTemp As System.IO.FileStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(strFileName)
                fileTemp.Close()
            Catch ex As Exception
                blnFileOpen = False
            End Try

            If System.IO.File.Exists(strFileName) Then
                System.IO.File.Delete(strFileName)
            End If
            wBook.SaveAs(strFileName)
            excel.Workbooks.Open(strFileName)
            excel.Visible = True
```

It is giving me error Public member 'Value' on type 'Integer' not found. Though this condition works with itextsharp i mean for PDF creation time. please help me. if remove that condition and run the code then it will create an excel file with image column as 'System.Byte[]'.

Comment: the error means what it says.  you got a DGV cell value into `cj` which in this case is an integer, `Int32` does nto have a Value property

Comment: @Plutonix the problem was with '.value' of cj. after removing as jmcilhinney suggest, condition worked but i didn't the desired output i.e. excel sheet including image from datagridview

Answer (score 0):

I get the feeling that you think that you're storing the grid cell in `cj` and then getting the `Value` of that cell but you have actually already got the `Value` of the cell and put that into `cj`.  Get rid of the `Value` property access on the following line and your code will likely work:

```
Dim cj = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value
```

By the way, don't do this:

```
If (cj.Value.GetType = GetType(Byte())) Then
```

It would be preferable to do this in isolation:

```
If TypeOf cj.Value Is Byte() Then
```

but, given that you're going to cast as that type if it is then you should use `TryCast` instead:

```
Dim data As Byte() = TryCast(cj.Value, Byte())

If data IsNot Nothing Then
    'Use data here.
End If
```

`TryCast` is like `DirectCast` except that it returns `Nothing` if the cast fails rather than throwing an exception.

Comment: I changed now the condition works and byte array converts to image but when i run the code the generated excel file show 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' instead of image.

Comment: That indicates that the `Image` object is having its `ToString` method called and the result used to populate the cell.  I don't know the solution to that if you're not calling it explicitly.